# PayPal Credit Card Payment Processing Workflow - authorize, update amount (add to), capture

Tags: paypal

We are working on a payment plugin for our e-commerce solution and having trouble with a workflow we wish to accomplish.

The workflow we want to provide would be as follows:

1. Customer adds items to cart.
2. Customer provides Credit Card information and submits order.
3. Store Owner calculates shipping and manually updates order total.
4. Order is processed and payment captured.

We seem to be running into an issue with 'authorize and capture' as credit cards are authorized for one amount and we cannot then 're-authorize' for the total (to include shipping fee).

Additionally we cannot do any kind of % over total to authorize, as the shipping fees can vary significantly.

Are we missing something in the API docs that will allow this workflow?

Comment: The issue is the "manual" part. If you could automate things there's [Instant Update](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECInstantUpdateAPI/?mark=payflow%20instant%20update) for Express Checkout and of course, for Direct Payments (calculate tax and shipping because you already have that data) then this would be moot. Paypal has [limits to what you can Capture over an Authorization](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/authcapture/?mark=capture%20amount). Hth.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!